# ffmpeg - MXF with 4-channel audio: how to create proxies (high quality / small file size) and preserve the audio mapping

Tags: ffmpeg

We've got MXF sources (h.264 video at UHD (3840x2160) with 4-channels of (4 - PCM S24 mono sources)
We want Proxies -- smallest file size at highest picture quality
The compression applied to the video and audio essences can be anything,
And the wrapper can be either MXF or QuickTime
but we need to preserve the audio mapping (i.e. the Proxy must be 4-channel audio)

How to do that with ffmpeg?

- EDIT Adding ffprobe:

> Metadata:
>
> uid             : ***
>
> generation_uid  : ***
>
> company_name    : CANON
>
> product_name    : EOS C300 Mark II
>
> product_version : 1.00
>
> product_uid     : ***
>
> modification_date: 2018-06-28T08:29:24.000000Z
>
> material_package_umid: ***
>
> timecode        : 02:50:31:17
>
> Duration: 00:06:35.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 395842 kb/s
>
> Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High 4:2:2 Intra), yuv422p10le(tv, progressive), 3840x2160, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 23.98 tbn, 47.95 tbc
>
> Metadata:
>
> ```
>  file_package_umid: ***
> ```
>
> Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
>
> Metadata:
>
> ```
>  file_package_umid: ***
> ```
>
> Stream #0:2: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
>
> Metadata:
>
> ```
>  file_package_umid: ***
> ```
>
> Stream #0:3: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
>
> Metadata:
>
> ```
>  file_package_umid: ***
> ```
>
> Stream #0:4: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
>
> Metadata:
>
> ```
>  file_package_umid: ***
> ```

Comment: What's the output of `ffprobe in.mxf`?

Comment: Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High 4:2:2 Intra), yuv422p10le(tv, progressive), 3840x2160, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 23.98 tbn, 47.95 tbc

Comment: Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s

Comment: The above is abbreviated to fit, including only one of the 4 audio tracks.  (There are three more, all the same)  There's a lot of other data excluded here: UID, time code, metadata (I'm assuming it's irrelevant in this context)
LMK if you need anything else.

Comment: Add the full log to the Q, not as comments. What codec do you want for the proxy?

Comment: Full log added above. For the proxy: h.264 for picture, aac for sound is fine.  Specific codec is less important than a) Matching the audio assigns of the original file; b) Highest quality for lowest file size and the ability to dial them to fit our needs.

Answer (score 0):

Basic command syntax would be

```
ffmpeg -i in.mxf -map 0 -g 48 -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -crf 16 -c:a aac -b:a 256k out.mp4
```

This will preserve all audio streams and in the same order as the source. Play with the crf value for quality/size - smaller value = greater size and quality. `g` sets GOP size in frames. In case your editor has a limited H264 decoder, try `-pix_fmt` with values `yuv422p` or `yuv420p` in that order.

Comment: Thanks Gyan!  The above code + "-pix_fmt" option didn't work, neither at 422 nor 420.  What did work was using "format" in place of "-pix_fmt" under "-vf scale".  So where you have "-b:a 256k" I added, immediately following " -vf scale=1280:720,format=yuv420p" (yuv422p did not work)  SO full line of code is "ffmpeg -i In.mxf -map 0 -g 48 -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -crf 16 -c:a aac -b:a 256k  -vf scale=1280:720,format=yuv420p Out.mp4"  Thanks again.  Brilliant on your part.

Comment: No doubt.  I would prefer not to mush the two together, but I've never been able to get pix_fmt to work.  pix_fmt an option that works independently of the -vf option (i.e. -pix_fmt), correct?  Whereas format operates under the umbrella of the -vf option.  Am I understanding this?

Comment: ffmpeg -i In.mxf -map 0 -g 48 -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -crf 16 -c:a aac -b:a 256k -vf scale=1280:720 -pix_format yuv420p Out.mp4

Comment: It's `-pix_fmt yuv420p`

Comment: What's horrendous is I knew that already, tested it multiple times, and probably somehow nonetheless kept typing "format" instead of "fmt" over and over again.  Your solution works perfectly.  At long last.  Thanks for all this.